# How can I control python thread when I send a lot requests in a limitless loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, grequests

Here is the situation.
  I need to send a ajax request to a Django view function every second and this view function will send some asynchronous requests to a third party API to get some data by grequests. These data will render to HTML after this view function returned.
here show the code

```
  desc_ip_list=['58.222.24.253', '58.222.17.38']
  reqs = [grequests.get('%s%s' % ('http://int.dpool.sina.com.cn/iplookup/iplookup.php?format=json&ip=', desc_ip))
        for desc_ip in desc_ip_list]
  response = grequests.map(reqs)
```

When I runserver django and send this ajax request,  the amount of threads of python is always increasing until error "can't start new thread" happened.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wmdk.jpg)

```
error: can't start new thread
<Greenlet at 0x110473b90: <bound method AsyncRequest.send of <grequests.AsyncRequest object at 0x1103fd1d0>>(stream=False)> 
failed with error
```

How can I control the amount of threads?  I have no idea of it because I'm a beginner pythoner.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your `desc_ip_list` is too long, and thus for let's say, a hundred IPs, you'd be spawning 100 requests, made by 100 threads!

[See here in the grequests code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py#L107).

**What you should do:**

**You should probably specify the `size` param in the `map()` call to a reasonable number,** 
probably (2*n+1) where n is the number of cores in your CPU, *at max*. It will make sure that you don't process all the IPs in the `desc_ip_list` at the same time, thereby spawning as many threads.

EDIT: More info, from a [gevent doc page](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html#gevent.pool.Pool):

> The Pool class, which is a subclass of Group, provides a way to limit concurrency: its spawn method blocks if the number of greenlets in the pool has already reached the limit, until there is a free slot.

Why am I mentioning this?
Let's trace it back from grequests:

In `map()`, we have from lineno 113-114:

```
pool = Pool(size) if size else None
jobs = [send(r, pool, stream=stream) for r in requests]
```

And in lineno 85 in `send()`, we have:

```
return gevent.spawn(r.send, stream=stream)
```

This is the return statement that will be executed from `send()`,
because its param `pool` will be None, because in map(), you didn't specify `size`. Now go back a few lines above and read what I quoted from the gevent docs.